# Front door shuts/locks but still gives about a quarter inch when pushed

Tags: doors

The front door to our house shuts completely and the locks work correctly.  There is weather stripping between the outside surface of the door and the door jamb.

If I push on the closed door from the inside near the handle it gives a little over 0.25 inches.  I find this peculiar as I have not seen this in past houses.  We have even had false positives from the alarm in the past although that has subsided in recent months (the switch is near the hinges).  I'm also concerned that this may be impacting our air conditioning.

What are some options for reducing the amount of give when the door is closed?

Comment: Open the door and take a look at the strike plate on the jamb.  Is it adjustable? Is it loose, or not set as far in (towards the exterior) as it could be?

Comment: Tester is correct that the strike plate should probably be moved to the exterior. Depending on the plate, you can sometimes get 1/8" movement simply by bending the small tab inside the cutout.

Comment: Thanks guys - I'll take a look at bending the tab.  I'm hesitant to try and move the strike plate as any new screw holes would be too close to the existing ones.

Comment: @Mayo, you could always fill the existing screw holes with toothpicks and wood glue and re-drill them using a guide.